# Generating an arc in p5.js with known center, start, and end coordinates

Tags: javascript, vector, processing, p5.js, curve

I'm attempting to do some vector visualization in p5.js. I'm having trouble with getting my arcs looking right. By parsing the file, I have the start (x1, y1), end (x2, y2), and center (xc, yc) coordinates of any given curve. When I try to draw my arc, the below image is what comes out. It's clearly on the right track, but it seems to ignore the endpoint of the arc. Any thoughts?

Adjusting the diameter in this case does not fix it.

[image: Incomplete curve]

Here's what I'm trying (ignore the scaling my vector formatting needs some work):

```
var info = generateArcAngle(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, prevCoordinates.x, prevCoordinates.y, coordinates.i, coordinates.j);
                    
var xc = (info.xcenter / 100000) - 1000;
var yc = (info.ycenter / 100000) + 1300;

var x1 = (prevCoordinates.x / 100000) - 1000;
var y1 = (prevCoordinates.y / 100000) + 1300;
                    
var x2 = (coordinates.x / 100000) - 1000;
var y2 = (coordinates.y / 100000) + 1300;

line(xc, yc, x2, y2)
line(xc, yc, x1, y1)

stroke('blue')
arc(xc, yc, info.diameter / 100000, info.diameter / 100000, info.startAngle, info.stopAngle)

strokeWeight(2)
stroke("magenta")
point(xc, yc)
point(x1, y1)
point(x2, y2)

function generateArcAngle(xstart, ystart, xend, yend, xoffset, yoffset) {
    var xcenter = xstart + xoffset;
    var ycenter = ystart + yoffset;
    var stopAngle;
    var startAngle;
    
    var arcInfo;

    var diameter = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xend - xcenter, 2) + Math.pow(yend - ycenter, 2)) * 2;

    
    stopAngle = atan2(yend - ycenter, xend - xcenter);
    startAngle = atan2(ystart - ycenter, xstart - xcenter);

    arcInfo = {xcenter: xcenter, ycenter: ycenter, startAngle: startAngle, stopAngle: stopAngle, diameter: diameter };

    return arcInfo;
}
```